# Start kotlin activity *.kt from java activity *.java?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, kotlin

***Invalidate Caches/ restart... helps me!***

My code in java class is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(view.getActivity(), AddPaymentActivity.class);
view.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

AddPaymentActivity has kotlin extention `.kt`
Got error **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError**

Comment: this is a problem with your build. Please post your gradle.build

Comment: @voddan so can you please provide link to answer in SO I can't find it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: now I realised the answer I was thinking about was out of date. Sorry for misleading

Comment: Your build looks fine to me, but that exception usually appears when Gradle plugins are misconfigured

Answer (score 7, accepted):

File -> Invalidate Caches/ restart...

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I forgot to add

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

and

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
...
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
```

to `build.gradle`

**Example**

project `build.gradle`

```
...
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    ...
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
  }
}
```

app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
...

dependencies {
  ...
  compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: And then invalidate cache and restart
File ->Invalidate Caches/ Restart

Answer (score 4):

There is no real difference between classes produced by Java and Kotlin. If your code is statically resolved by Android Studio (as it should), then it must run unless Gradle is misconfigured.

Answer (score 3):

You just do it like "normally" in Java:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), KotlinActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Just don't forget to add Kotlin to your project fist (in the gradle files). Otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone struggling inspite of all these answers, in my case, I forgot to add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'` inside the app level's `build.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

Add Kotlin in your java project

1. This should be your build.gradle(Project level)
   [image]

[image: Add this kolin plugin in build.gradle module level]

[image: Add this in your depedency]

Hope it work for u ,worked for me