# How to intent from a java class to a kotlin class in Android Studios

Tags: java, android, android-intent, kotlin

I am trying to access a kotlin class (b.kt) from a java class (a.java).

```
Intent intent = new Intent(a.this,b.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

But I am getting this `error: cannot find symbol class RegisterActivity`.

Is there a way to access a `kotlin` class from a `java` class?

Here is where I called b.kt on a.java

```
bt_click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(a.this,b.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is b.kt

```
package com.example.android.app123

    import android.app.Activity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    import android.util.Log
    import android.widget.EditText


    class b: AppCompatActivity() {


        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            requestWindowFeature(android.view.Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_register)


        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877952/start-kotlin-activity-kt-from-java-activity-java

Comment: It should be accessed as a regural Java class. Post the code of the `b` class decralation, and further usage from java

Comment: Please see my edit. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've tried to use your classes, and it worked like it should:
[image]
As you can see it can use `b` and get `class` from it. (of course I don't have `activity_register` layout so it is red)

Probably the problem lays not in the Java-Kotlin relation, but in something else. Please check your code/project. I would guess that there is also an variable `b` that shadow your activity, but I think that in real code, your activity isn't called `b`.

Comment: I just realized that I have accidentally deleted "apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'" in the gradle. Its working now. Thanks man!

Comment: Mistakes are often hidden in a simple places :) Glad helped

Comment: I did it same way but my activity layout not inflating. Any help is appreciable. This first time I am calling kotlin activity from java class

Comment: @KalpanaAneyrao, can say like this. post a question with your code.